# Using select() to detect a block on a UIO device file

Tags: c, select, blocking

I'm working on an embedded processor running Yocto. I have a modified *uio_pdrv_genirq.c* UIO driver.

I am writing a library to control the DMA. There is one function which writes to the device file and initiates the DMA. A second function is intended to wait for the DMA to complete by calling *select()*. Whilst DMA is in progress the device file blocks. On completion the DMA controller issues an interrupt which releases the block on the device file.

I have the system working as expected using *read()* but I want to switch to *select()* so that I can include a time out. However, when I use *select()*, it doesn't seem to be recognising the block and always returns immediately (before the DMA has completed). I have included a simple version of the code:

```
int gannet_dma_interrupt_wait(dma_device_t *dma_device,
        dma_direction dma_transfer_direction) {

    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval timeout;
    int select_res;

    /* Initialize the file descriptor set and add the device file */
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(dma_device->fd, &rfds);

    /* Set the timeout period. */
    timeout.tv_sec = 5;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    /* The device file will block until the DMA transfer has completed. */
    select_res = select(FD_SETSIZE, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

    /* Reset the channel */
    gannet_dma_reset(dma_device, dma_transfer_direction);

    if (select_res == -1) {
        /* Select has encountered an error */
        perror("ERROR <Interrupt Select Failed>\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (select_res == 1) {
        /* The device file descriptor block released */
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        /* The device file descriptor block exceeded timeout */
        return EINTR;
    }
}
```

Is there anything obviously wrong with my code? Or can anyone suggest an alternative to select?

Comment: After further investigation it turns out that `select()` will function as expected if I include a `read()` afterwards. I have confirmed that it is the `select()` call which is blocking by timing both functions in this case. Could it be that when I only call `select()` the compiler realises I never actually do a `read()` and optimises the `select()` out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the UIO driver contains two counters. One records the
number of events (`event_count`), the other records how many events the
calling function is aware of (`listener->event_count`).

When you do a `read()` on a UIO driver it returns the number of events and
makes `listener->event_count` equal to `event_count`. ie. the listener is
now up to date with all the events that have occurred.

When you use `poll()` or `select()` on a UIO driver, it checks if these two
numbers are different and returns if they are (if they are the same it
waits until they differ and then returns). It does NOT update the
`listener->event_count`.

Clearly if you do not do a `read()` between calls to `select()` then
the `listener->event_count` will not match the `event_count` and the second
`select()` will return immediately. **Therefore it is necessary to call
`read()` in between calls to `select()`.**

With hindsight it seems clear that `select()` should work in this way but it wasn't obvious to me at the time.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that it is possible to use select() as intented for the specified device file (I use select() for socket descriptors only). As an alternative function to select(), you may want to check out the poll() family of functions. What follows will hopefully at least offer hints as to what can be done to resolve your problem with calling select().

The first parameter to the select() function has to be the maximum despriptor number plus 1. Since you have only one descriptor, you can pass it directly to select() as its first parameter and add 1. Also consider that the file descriptor in dma_device could be invalid. Returning EINTR on a timeout may actually be what you intend to do but should that not be the case and to test for an invalid descriptor, here is a different version for you to consider. The select() call could be interrupted by a signal, in which case, the return value is -1 and errno will be set to EINTR. This could be handled internally by your function as in:

```
FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_SET(dma_device->fd, &rfds);

timeout.tv_sec = 5;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

// restart select() if it's interrupted by a signal;

do {

  select_res = select(dma_device->fd + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

}
while( select_res < 0 && errno == EINTR);


if (select_res > 0) {

  // a file descriptor is legible

}
else {

  if (select_res == 0) {

    // select() timed-out
  }
  else  {

    // an error other than a signal occurred

    if (errno == EBADF) {

      // your file descriptor is invalid 

    }
  } 
}
```